# Regex not working as field separator on awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have this text file `foo.txt` which contains words mixed with punctuation marks.

What I want to do is filter every punctuation mark using `awk`, so I used a regex expression as field separator, like this `awk -F '[^a-zA-Z]+' '{ print $0 }' foo.txt`, the problem I'm facing is that the text stays just like the original, nothing is filtered.

Anyone knows why this happens?

**Input**

`¿Hello? How... are foo you?'
Bye ,, hehe '" .lol`

**Result Expected**
`Hello How are foo you 
Bye hehe lol`

P.D
I know I can achieve the same result using sed with something like this `sed 's/[[:punct:]]//g' foo.txt` or `sed s/[^A-Za-z]/" "/g foo.txt`, but I want to know why the `awk` command is not working, I've already investigated everywhere and I can't find an answer, I'm not going to be able to sleep.

Comment: `$0` is the *whole* line!

Comment: With the field-separators removed... I don't understand your question. In both cases `awk -F '[^a-zA-Z]+' '{ print $0 }' foo.txt` or `sed 's/[[:punct:]]//g' foo.txt` you are telling each to remove (everything not upper or lower case with `awk) and (all punctuation with `sed`), the result being the same. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Omg! Thank you! @Emi

Comment: I was trying to figure out why the awk command I was trying to use wasn't working @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: But I learned a lot of things in the last 30 minutes, so I thought that awk wasn't taking the field separator into consideration when it actually was. The problem is I didn't accessed the values in a correct way. @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: I'm curious - what made you think to use a field separator for this task instead of just `awk '{gsub(/[[:punct:]]/,"")}1'` like you did in sed? Hopefully you know that `[^a-zA-Z]` is not equivalent to `[[:punct:]]` btw.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know where you can find the rules behind this, I would like to point to [Awk POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html):

However, you have to find the answer a bit on two locations:

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The awk utility shall interpret each input record as a sequence of fields where, by default, a field is a string of non- <blank> non- <newline> characters. This default <blank> and <newline> field delimiter can be changed by using the `FS` built-in variable or the `-F` sepstring option. The awk utility shall denote the first field in a record `$1`, the second `$2`, and so on. **The symbol `$0` shall refer to the entire record; setting any other field causes the re-evaluation of `$0`**. Assigning to `$0` shall reset the values of all other fields and the `NF` built-in variable.
>
> **Variables and Special Variables**
>
> References to nonexistent fields (that is, fields after `$NF`), shall evaluate to the uninitialized value. Such references shall not create new fields. However, assigning to a nonexistent field (for example, `$(NF+2)=5`) shall increase the value of `NF`; create any intervening fields with the uninitialized value; and **cause the value of `$0` to be recomputed, with the fields being separated by the value of `OFS`**. Each field variable shall have a string value or an uninitialized value when created. Field variables shall have the uninitialized value when created from `$0` using `FS` and the variable does not contain any characters.

It is a bit `awk`ward to find the rule for recomputing `$0` when new fields are introduced, but this is essentially the rule.

Furthermore, the statement `print $0` prints the entire field. So according to the above, you first need to recompute your `$0` as shown in the answer of [@oguzismail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52196934/8344060).

So changing the field separator can be done in the following way:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="oldFS"; OFS="newFS"}{$1=$1}1' <file>
```

***remark:*** you do not need to check if the line contains any fields as `NF{$1=$1}` since `{$1=$1}` will just introduce an empty field without an extra `OFS`.